# Combining tables with different columns names, without duplication in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables.

[image: TableA] and
[image: TableB]

I want to combine the data from both tables on corresponding columns 'UnitID' and Unit_WO' without duplication.
I have tried several join combinations but still getting duplications.

Following is the result that I am getting.
[image: Result]

Can you guys please guide? Should I use Cursor to pick data from each row from both tables?

these are the queries that I tried.

```
--Query option1--
select  
(select distinct Row_number() over (partition by fc.unitid order by fc.Unit_wo asc) as src_RowID_Unit), fc.UnitID, fc.Unit_WO, srcUnitName, srcMaterialName, srcBatchId, srcUnitofMeasure, srcSegment1, srcSegment2, srcSegment3, srcSegment4, srcSegment5, srcAmount, srcStartDate, srcEndDate

,(select distinct Row_number() over (partition by fp.unitid order by fp.Unit_wo asc) as trgt_RowID_Unit), trgtUnitName, trgtMaterialName, trgtBatchId, trgtUnitofMeasure, trgtSegment1, trgtSegment2, trgtSegment3, trgtSegment4, trgtSegment5, trgtAmount, trgtStartDate, trgtEndDate

from @Finaltable_cons fc
right join @Finaltable_prod fp on  fc.Unit_WO = fp.Unit_WO  


    --query option 2--

SELECT 

distinct fc.UnitID, fc.Unit_WO, srcUnitName, srcMaterialName, srcBatchId, srcUnitofMeasure, srcSegment1, srcSegment2, srcSegment3, srcSegment4, srcSegment5, srcAmount, srcStartDate, srcEndDate, fp.UnitID, fp.Unit_WO, trgtUnitName, trgtMaterialName, trgtBatchId, trgtUnitofMeasure, trgtSegment1, trgtSegment2, trgtSegment3, trgtSegment4, trgtSegment5, trgtAmount, trgtStartDate, trgtEndDate

FROM @Finaltable_cons fc, @Finaltable_prod fp
WHERE fc.UnitID = fp.UnitID and  fc.Unit_WO = fp.Unit_WO 
group by  fc.UnitID, fc.Unit_WO;
```

Comment: Add the query you've tried to your question.

Comment: You can use ``Partition by`` to select one row for each condition.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you have a Table1 (Source) and Table2 (Target), Both of them have UnitID, Unit_WO which are unique in their tables, Now you want to put all data together from these tables in 1 row if they have same UnitID and Unit_WO, But you want this 2 column still be unique.

In below query you can achieve this, Even if you have UnitID and Unit_WO in either table which not exists in other table.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN tbl1.UnitID IS NULL THEN tbl2.UnitID ELSE tbl1.UnitID END AS UnitID,
    CASE WHEN tbl1.Unit_WO IS NULL THEN tbl2.Unit_WO ELSE tbl1.Unit_WO END AS Unit_WO,
    tbl1.srcUnitName,
    tbl1.srcBatchID,
    tbl2.trgtUnitName,
    tbl2.trgtBatchID
FROM dbo.Table1 tbl1
     FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Table2 tbl2 ON tbl2.Unit_WO=tbl1.Unit_WO
                                        AND tbl2.UnitID=tbl1.UnitID
```

This all will be OK if both table be unique on UnitID and Unit_WO

Comment: Columns should be the same as shown in my result table. All column names starting with 'src' and 'trgt' have different values. All they have common is 'unitID' and 'Unit_WO'.

Comment: If I try to combine these 2 tables, one with src values and one with trgt values, I am having duplication in 'uniID' and 'Unit_WO' columns. This I need to avoid. One 'UnitID' can have multiple 'Unit_WO'.  One 'Unit_WO can have 1 'srcUnitName' but multiple 'trgtUnitName' or  vice versa. There should not be any duplication when I combine these 2 tables, in case of ,'srcUnitName' or 'trgtUnitName and corresponding data' for particular 'Unit_WO. This is my end result.

Comment: I changed my answer base on what i understand if your comments